# Что установить в Visual studio 2017 для разработки на c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Я решил установить Visual studio 2017 enterprise и возник вопрос: где поставить галочки для разработки на c#. Знаю что можно позже установить оставшийся контент, так что скажите все, что связано с c#(Веб, геймдев, софт, и мобильная разработка)[image: Что тут отметить?[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpAbo.jpg)

Comment: Я последнее время перешёл на JetBrains Rider, он занимает в разы меньше места, а возможности больше, глючит меньше. Продуман для людей.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин - сами покупали Rider али работодатель оплатил?

Comment: Впрочем, о чём я: если человеку по карману VS Enterprise...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Rider к сожалению дорого стоит, и бесплатной версии нету, это, конечно большой минус. Ну да, в данном комментарии я Rider сравниваю с Enterprize версией. Если человек может поставить себе  Enterprize VS то думаю и Rider сможет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин У JetBrains есть очень крутая вешь, как "лицензия для OpenSource", бесплатно почти все продукты отдают. Советую, если начинающий разработчик, или разрабатываете бесплатно для "души"/развития навыков.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ого, очень важная информация, так как я делаю как раз такой проект, а можно ссылочку поподробнее узнать, а на Rider тоже есть?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Выдается так называемый `All Products Pack`, который включает в себя IntelliJ, IDEA Ultimate, ReSharper, ReSharper C++, dotTrace, dotMemory, dotCover, AppCode, CLion, PhpStorm, PyCharm, RubyMine, WebStorm, DataGrip, Rider, GoLand. [Ссылка на получение](https://www.jetbrains.com/buy/opensource/). Еще удобно то, что лицензия будет ваша, пока живет проект и ее можно получить для всей команды.

Comment: В VS сделали почти идеальный инсталлятор, в котором можно нажать одну галочку и он установит все что необходимо, а не как раньше: приходилось из большого списка выбирать и думать, нужно ли это ставить. И после этого человек не может прочитать описания пунктов (на русском языке) и поставить галочку в нужном месте? Господа, я в шоке, зачем он в программирование полез?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity - для игр как раз подходит.

Если разрабываете на C#, то всё что про C++ можно не ставить.

Core думаю лучше поставить, это современный новый кроссплатформенный .NET.

Расширения вам врятли нужны будут.

Мобильную разработку, если вы только начинаете програмировать думаю можно не ставить, сначала надо с базой разобраться, а когда потребуется, возможно это будет уже другая версия VS.